# Variations of S-matrix functional and Feynman diagrams in Weinberg QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, variational-principle, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions

Weinberg on p. 287 of his QFT vol. 1 introduces the extended interaction operator:
$$
\tag 1 \hat{V}(t) \to \hat{V}(t) + \sum_{a}\int d^{3}\mathbf x \hat{o}_{a}(\mathbf x ,t)\varepsilon_{a}(x).
$$
Here 
$$
\hat{S} = \hat{T}e^{i\int \hat{V}(t)dt}, \quad \hat{o}_{a}(\mathbf x, t) = e^{i\hat{H}_{0}t}\hat{o}_{a}(\mathbf x , 0)e^{-i\hat{H}_{0}t}.
$$

Then he says that S-matrix arbitrary element $S_{\beta \alpha} = \langle \beta | \hat{S}| \alpha \rangle$ after extension $(1)$ becomes the $\varepsilon $-functional, and after that he introduces generalized Feynman rules by adding new vertexes corresponding to $\hat{o}_{a}$ with $n_{a}$ lines (the number $n_{a}$ coincides with the number of fields in $\hat{o}_{a}$) and c-factor $\varepsilon_{a}$.

After that he introduces variational derivative
$$
\tag 2 \left( \frac{\delta^{r}S_{\beta \alpha}}{\delta \varepsilon_{a_{1}}(x_{1})...\delta \varepsilon_{a_{r}}(x_{r})}\right)_{\varepsilon = 0} = (i)^{r}\langle \beta | \hat{T}\left(e^{i\int \hat{V}(t)dt} \hat{o}_{a_{1}}(x_{1})...\hat{o}_{a_{r}}(x_{r})\right)|\alpha\rangle 
$$
and notices that all $n_{a_{1}}, ..., n_{a_{r}}$ lines correspond to $\hat{o}_{a_{1}},...,\hat{o}_{a_{r}}$ respectively are internal, i.e. in case when $n_{a_{1}} = ... = n_{a_{r}} = 1$ they are compared to the propagators.

Finally, he says, that if we want to get Feynman diagram with $r$ external lines with types $a_{1},...,a_{r}$ in momentum representation we need to do following with $(2)$:

1) to throw out of propagators $D_{a_{1}a_{r}}(x_{1} - x_{r})$,

2) to apply the Fourier transformation,

3) to add corresponding coefficient functions $u_{a_{1}},...$.

Here is the question: сould you make the sense of introduction of mechanism 1)-3) clearer for me? Why do we need additional $r$ external lines which with corresponding vertexes which aren't connected to other vertexes (so the diagram is non-connected), as I think?

I need to rephrase the question. I know that n-point Green functions $\langle \beta | \hat{T}\left(\hat{o}^{H}_{a_{1}}(x_{1})...\right)|\alpha \rangle$ where the operators are in Heisenberg picture are equal to $(2)$. Also these functions are widely used for derivation of some non-perturbative results for scattering processes. But I don't understand how to apply these non-perturbative results for S-matrix, because we need to set $r$ to zero for obtaining the exact sets of Feynman amplitudes $S_{\beta \alpha}$, but I'm not sure that it is possible without loss of nonperturbative results. Here is some incorrect understanding of Weinberg method, so it will be very good if someone help me.

Comment: Have a look to [LSZ reduction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula#The_reduction_formula_for_scalars) (more precisely the second-to-last formula in the chapter "The reduction formula for scalars")